# How do I create a ruby Hello world?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I know in PHP you have to intrepret a page like `index.php`, but in Ruby how does it work? I don't know what is the Ruby extension like `index.php` for PHP. Could you help me?

Answer (score 94, accepted):

If you are talking about a command line program this will work.

```
puts "Hello World"
```

or if you want an object oriented version

```
class HelloWorld
   def initialize(name)
      @name = name.capitalize
   end
   def sayHi
      puts "Hello #{@name}!"
   end
end

hello = HelloWorld.new("World")
hello.sayHi
```

If you are looking for a ruby on rails version of Hello World.
Check the Getting Started [Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html#hello-rails-bang) for Rails.

Comment: I'm afraid you'd better have a look at the suggested Ruby On Rails tutorials before...

Comment: @toddoon Those are command line hello world programs written in ruby. It looks like you are more interested in ruby as a web programming language. Rails is the tool you need to be looking at. I linked a guide in my answer.

Comment: I have this error now
Application error
Rails application failed to start properly"

Comment: How do i execute command in terminal like ruby script/generate because I have no ssh console?

Comment: use cmd.exe or powershell.exe.

Comment: Or, if you like, you could install cygwin and use bash. If you prefer a gui, you could alternatively use something like the Aptana IDE rails mode.

Comment: Rails is like a sledge hammer for many Ruby/web tasks. [Sinatra](http://www.sinatrarb.com/) is very lightweight and a great starting point as you learn Ruby and [HAML](http://haml-lang.com/) or [ERB](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/ERB.html) templating.

Answer (score 28):

You can take a look at this [Ruby Programming Wiki](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_Programming/Hello_world) on Wikibooks

Code:

```
puts 'Hello world'
```

Run:

```
$ ruby hello-world.rb
Hello world
```

Answer (score 8):

This is how to write a very simple "hello world" using [Sinatra](http://www.sinatrarb.com/), which is a great way to bring up a Ruby-based website without using Rails. The sample is basically the same as the Sinatra folks have on the front page of their site. It's really this simple.

Install the Sinatra gem along with its dependencies:

```
`gem install sinatra`
```

Save this to a file called `hi.rb`:

```
require 'sinatra'

get '/hi' do
  "Hello World!"
end
```

Drop to the command-line, and enter `ruby hi.rb`. After a few seconds you should see something like:

```
== Sinatra/1.1.0 has taken the stage on 4567 for development with backup from WEBrick
[2010-12-04 11:43:43] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
[2010-12-04 11:43:43] INFO  ruby 1.9.2 (2010-08-18) [x86_64-darwin10.5.0]
[2010-12-04 11:43:43] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=37898 port=4567:
```

By default Sinatra serves its pages at `port=4567`, but you can change it. Read [the docs](http://www.sinatrarb.com/documentation) to learn how.

Open a new window in your browser, and go to:

```
http://localhost:4567/hi
```

and you should see `Hello World!` in your browser window.

Sinatra is really easy to work with, and makes a great prototyping and light-to-medium weight MVC-like server. I love it because of its easy integration with [Sequel](http://sequel.rubyforge.org/), my favorite ORM, and [HAML](http://haml-lang.com/), which replaces ERB as the templating engine.

Sinatra's [Intro doc](http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro.html) is a great starting point. The [Sinatra Book](http://sinatra-book.gittr.com/) is a good resource too.

Answer (score 7):

**How does it work in Ruby?**

Ruby is a scripting language (not compiled) just like php (as you said "you have to intrepet a page") and python, bin/bash, etc...in Ruby you have libraries with helpers and very very cool stuff they are called "**gems**" (Ruby and Gems :D nice name convention right? BTW this is because Ruby's parent is Perl).

You can organized different files inside one Ruby's project folder, it could be in this case one *.rb file and one "**Gemfile**" (that's the name without extension) in which you define which "gems" you want to install in your Ruby app (read about **bundler**), only with this two files you will be able to successfully do anything you want **but** as a **desktop app** (by this i mean that the Ruby app you write will only be executable on a computer with Ruby installed, and you have to install it manually (with **bundler** so all required "**gems**" are in there) and then manually run Ruby's command targeting your code's main class (unless of course you create a **cron-job** that do this automatically for you, pretty common practice to run processes on web servers).

If you want to use Ruby to create a "**webapp**" , website , etc right now two pretty popular choices are using the "**rails**" framework and "**sinatra**" gem.

With rails (that's why you hear much about ruby on rails) framework you are able to execute commands to create new website project, remember that rails uses the coding pattern called **MVC** (model view controller) so you will have plenty options for creating your models, views and controllers individually or using "scaffold" that will create all of them for you, rails will create a bunch of files and some of them will not be *.rb of Gemfile, all of them will have a specific task: configuration files for database, labels, of config or other "gems" you install besides rails.Take in mind that rails offer stuff for **TDD** (test driven development) so in a matter of hours you can have a fully functional website 100% tested and operational (**big infrastructure**).

This is why i also brought "sinatra" gem to this conversation...sinatra will give you same functionality than rails does but instead sinatra will not install anything for you (**leaving space for error** if you have not expertise on setting on web servers, web apps , etc) only the sinatra framework which will run a server for you on a specific port number so that way you can then add code to your main class in order to display HTML(**small infrastructure**)

**What is the Ruby extension like index.php for PHP?**

All ruby files are using *.rb

Hope this helps!

**PS: Hello world sample**

1. install ruby
2. create a new folder an inside create a file "hello.rb"
3. open the file and add the following code:

   puts 'Hello world'
4. close and save the file
5. now open a terminal, console, etc go to your ruby file folder path and run the following command:

   ruby hello.rb
6. that will print on your console:

   Hello world

Comment: Thanks for taking time out to write a clear high level overview. very helpful!

Answer (score 4):

```
puts "Hello, World!"
```

To run Ruby scripts on the web, you need to use a special server, run through (F)CGI, or do some other stuff; there are several ways to get different languages HTTP-accessible. However, the simplest way is probably to use a Ruby web framework, such as Ruby on Rails or Merb -- these projects include servers and all of the things you need to get going.

Answer (score 4):

Just copy and past this code on your terminal. Then hit enter.

```
ruby -e "puts 'Hello world'"
```

Answer (score 3):

I know the question was talking about Ruby, but I think you meant rails (which is what it was tagged as).  Rails is a web framework that uses the ruby programming language.

install rubyonrails.

Type:

```
rails projectname
cd projectname
ruby script/server
```

Navigate to http://localhost:3000

Comment: Ok thanx but i am on shared hosting and it tells me that I can interpret ruby. I have check 'activate rybyonrails'. What's then?

Comment: You need to check with your hosting provider.

Comment: You should update your question to include the name of your hosting provider, otherwise it will be hard to help you with this.